# ModelState.AddModelError dosen't show error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My ModelState.AddModelError dosen't show an error.
I checked the username and show an error when its been duplicated.
When I use a breakpoint I see ModelState.AddModelError is filled, it just doesn't show the error msg.

My code:

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(tbl_User model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (MyClass.IsUserNameDuplicate(model.username) == true)
            {
 this.ModelState.AddModelError("username", "the username is duplicate");

                return View(model);
            }
            else
            {
                MyClass.creatUser(model.username, model.password_User, model.nam);
            }
        }

        return View(model);

    }
```

View :

```
         @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.username) 
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.username, new {@class = "input", @placeholder = "*enter user name" })
```

Comment: try using `@Html.ValidationMessage("username")`

Comment: -1: just for the tag-spam

Comment: How are you calling this controller action? Are you using AJAX?

Comment: i used  @Html.ValidationMessage("username") and it worked . but when i have server side error and client side error together , it just shows clientside error .

Comment: +1: Tag SPAM was edited out, people. Upvote this if you found it helpful as I did.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `AddModelError` before checking `ModelState.IsValid`. I do this many times for custom validation in my controllers

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(tbl_User model)
{
    if (MyClass.IsUserNameDuplicate(model.username) == true)
    {
        this.ModelState.AddModelError("username", "the username is duplicate");
    }

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    else
    {
        MyClass.creatUser(model.username, model.password_User, model.nam);
    }

    return View(model);
}
```